# Flutter: How to add button under list view without error with scroll

Tags: flutter, testing, mobile, layout

I want to know how to add a button under the `list view` and add to this list view by button
without an error
and this by making `a scrollable list view`

[image: en ter image description here]

I want this because when adding to the list view from the button the list view gets an error on the screen

this an error

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 47 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was
Column
alert_list_screen.dart:39
You can inspect this widget using the 'Inspect Widget' button in the VS Code notification.
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#50fae relayoutBoundary=up6 OVERFLOWING
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

my code (screen & reusable widget)

NOTE I use cubit and the `newDepot` list is a place for storing data in

```
 var depot = DepotDatabaseCubit.get(context).newDepotList;

  Expanded(
    child: Container(
      child: depotBuilder(
             depot: depot,
          ),
        ),
      ),
     Container(
       child: elevatedButton(
          name: 'Add new depot',
             onPressed: () {
              ....
         },
      ),
   ),
```

the `elevatedButton` is a normal reusable widget to see the normal button but I just change the child widget to a name to add a label to the button

the `depotBuilder` widget
this widget takes data and presentation to the screen by list view

```
Widget depotBuilder({required List<Map> depot}) {
  return ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => depotItem(
      context: context,
      model: depot[index],
    ),
    itemCount: depot.length,
  );
}
```

the `depotItem`  is the item of the list view when running the app you will add the new item for the list view

```
Widget depotItem({
  required Map model,
  required BuildContext context,
}) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
    child: Container(
      height: 56,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        boxShadow: [
          containerBoxShadow(),
        ],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Text(
                ...
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Please share appropriate build method code for better understanding. Your present code shows Expanded widget directly, is it wrapped with some another parent widget, if yes, please share minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Expanded listview and button like below.

[image: sample is below]

```
Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 8,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 20,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return const Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text("Title"),
                          subtitle: Text("Subtitle"),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Center(child: Text("Add new item")),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SingleChildScrollView() inside a Column, for example:

```
Colum(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children:[
        SingleChildScrollView(),
        ElevatedButton(),
    ]
)
```